# Reverse a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hashmap

How would I reverse the elements in the hash, keeping the same values and keys, but reversing their order in the hash.

Like so:

```
{ "4" => "happiness", "10" => "cool", "lala" => "54", "1" => "spider" }
```

And convert that to:

```
{ "1" => "spider", "lala" => "54", "10" => "cool", "4" => "happiness" }
```

Or, perhaps I could run a `each` loop backwards, starting from the last element in the hash, rather than the first?

Comment: Not to be confused with inverting a hash (switching keys with values). http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could convert the Hash to an Array, reverse that, and then convert it back to a Hash:

```
reversed_h = Hash[h.to_a.reverse]
```

[`Hash#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-to_a) gives you an array of arrays, the inner arrays are simple `[key,value]` pairs, then you reverse that array using [`Array#reverse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-reverse), and [`Hash[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) converts the `[key,value]` pairs back into a Hash.

Ruby 2.1 adds an [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_h) method so you can now say:

```
reversed_h = h.to_a.reverse.to_h
```

Comment: reversed_h = Hash[h.to_a.collect(&:reverse)]

Comment: @P.S.V.R: There seems to be some confusion between the text of the question ("reverse the elements in the hash, keeping the **same values and keys**, but reversing their order in the hash" [emphasis mine]) and the example given. Apparently the text in the question was correct or slyv would have accepted steenslag's answer instead.

Comment: Thanks, it gives me a hint to do this:
`{"happiness"=>"4", "cool"=>"10", "54"=>"lala", "spider"=>"1"}`

Comment: {"happiness"=>"4", "cool"=>"10", "54"=>"lala", "spider"=>"1"}
by
`Hash[h.to_a.map {|x| x=x.reverse}]`

Comment: This throws a few warnings on ruby 2.1.2, you should instead use Hash.new(h.to_a.reverse)

Comment: @Waclock: What warnings are you getting with 2.1.2? Works fine for me. OTOH, with 2.1+ you can say `h.to_a.reverse.to_h`.

Comment: Actually I ended up using hash.reverse, Hash.new made an array of arrays.

Answer (score 13):

In Ruby 2.1+ you can combine [`reverse_each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reverse_each) and [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h):

```
{foo: 1, bar: 2}.reverse_each.to_h
#=> {:bar=>2, :foo=>1}
```

Comment: Nice, no temporary array that `reverse` would produce. [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h came with v 2.1, but [Enumerable#reverse_each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) has been around since at least v1.9.3. Alternatively, `h.reverse_each.with_object({}) } |(k,v),g| g[k]=v }`.

Answer (score 5):

In pure ruby, you can do it by `hash.map(&:reverse).to_h` or `hash.reverse_each.to_h`

In rails, you can do it by `hash.invert`

Comment: https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Hash/invert

invert() public
Returns a new hash created by using hsh’s values as keys, and the keys as values. If a key with the same value already exists in the hsh, then the last one defined will be used, the earlier value(s) will be discarded.

Answer (score 4):

```
hash = { "4" => "happiness", "10" => "cool", "lala" => "54", "1" => "spider" }
reversed_hash = Hash[hash.to_a.reverse]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
h = { "4" => "happiness", "10" => "cool", "lala" => "54", "1" => "spider" }
p Hash[h.reverse_each.map{|e| e}]
#=> {"1"=>"spider", "lala"=>"54", "10"=>"cool", "4"=>"happiness"}
```

But this leaves a bad taste (just like the other answers, which work fine just like this one).  If you have to do this, it could be an indication that a Hash was not the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `reduce` and `merge` to add the item to the front of a new hash:

```
hash = { "4" => "happiness", "10" => "cool", "lala" => "54", "1" => "spider" }
hash.reduce({}){ |memo, object| Hash[*object].merge(memo) }
```

but, that's crazy :D

Answer (score 1):

```
reversed_h = Hash[h.to_a.collect(&:reverse)]
```

Comment: Why not simply `Hash[h.map { |k, v| [v, k] }]` or `Hash[h.map(&:reverse)]` then?

Answer (score 0):

In [Ruby 1.8.7](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html), the order of elements in a hash is documented to be not under our control, so none of the above methods work.  In [Ruby 1.9.3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html), things work and are documented in the way that the other answers rely upon.

```
$ irb1.8
h = { "4" => "happiness", "10" => "cool", "lala" => "54", "1" => "spider" }
Hash[h.to_a().reverse()]
=> {"lala"=>"54", "1"=>"spider", "10"=>"cool", "4"=>"happiness"}
quit
$ irb1.9.1
h = { "4" => "happiness", "10" => "cool", "lala" => "54", "1" => "spider" }
Hash[h.to_a().reverse()]
=>{"1"=>"spider", "lala"=>"54", "10"=>"cool", "4"=>"happiness"}
```

The Ruby 1.8.7 way was ingrained so firmly for me that I misunderstood the question for quite some time.  I thought it requested a way to [Hash#invert](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-invert): ie to transform the hash such that the range maps to the domain.  That method discards duplicates.  Luís Ramalho proffers [a method](http://www.luisramalho.com/how-to-invert-a-hash-in-ruby-and-not-overwriting-repeated-keys) that doesn't, but it's a bit clunky.  This is a little shorter:

```
$ irb
def invertWithDuplicates(original)
  inverse = Hash.new() { |hash, key| hash[key] = []; }
  original.each_pair() { |key, value| inverse[value].push(key); }
  return inverse
end
h = { "4" => "happiness", "10" => "cool", "lala" => "54", "1" => "cool" }
invertWithDuplicates(h)
=> {"happiness"=>["4"], "cool"=>["1", "10"], "54"=>["lala"]}
```

Sorry to drift away from the OP's intended topic, though I submit that this does fit the post's title "Reverse a hash in Ruby".

Comment: This is best answer so far. In fact, I'd guess that in most languages, there's no guarantee of key ordering. The keys are a set, not a list. It's important to keep in mind. It's so prevalent, I'd never use any of the techniques on this page. Instead, I'd order the hash as needed depending on the view's needs.

Answer (score 0):

if need:

```rb
hash = {:a => :x, :b => :y, :c => :y, :d => :z}
```

to:

```rb
{:x => [:a], :y => [:b, c], :z => [:d] }
```

can:

```rb
h={};hash.to_a.each{|e|h[e[1]]||=[];h[e[1]]<<e[0]};h
```